# integrating cube roots of rational functions

Tags: integration

I have found myself wanting to solve the following integral:

$$\int_a^{1/a} \frac{dv}{\left[v^5(v+1)^4(v^2+1)^5\right]^{1/3}}$$

where $$0<a<1.$$ As far as I can tell Mathematica is unable to solve this and I've exhausted all my ideas. Is there any chance that a solution to this integral in terms of known functions can be found?

EDIT: Whoops! I had written the v^2+1 root as (v^2-1)

Comment: You have elliptic and hyperelliptic integrals. This is not a gift.

Comment: Apart from the apparent lack of a closed form antiderivative, your integrand has a non-integrable singularity (like $(v-1)^{-5/3}$) at $v=1$, so the integral can only exist at best in the Cauchy principal value sense.

Comment: from where does this integral come?

Comment: I made a typo at first, there should be no singularities in the integration region at least. The integral comes from an obscure phase-space integral in a quantum field theory calculation. I've made a coordinate transformation that has allowed me to do the parts of the integral between [0,a] and [1/a,infinity], so I got excited, but I'm left with this...

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "Mathematica is unable to solve this" should make it clear that this integral cannot be done in terms of "elementary functions".  ("Almost all" integrable functions cannot be integrated in terms of elementary functions.)

Comment: True enough, but Mathematica is not perfect. There are plenty of integrals that Mathematica's Integrate function will fail to do that can be done using contour integration, for example. In any case, I was pretty sure it was hopeless when I posted the question, this is sort of a hail mary.